# Estimating the regression to the mean in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, mean, mixed-models

I am working with a set of 42345 patients, from those, I establish subsets as Obese/non-Obese etc

I am wondering if there is a way in R to estimate the regression to the mean.

This may be a [good resource](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/34/1/215/638499) in case someone who knows base R can help me. From this paper, I would be interested in expressing this equation in R: [image]

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards